# The lack of food, about the definite article "the"

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

If I want to tell somebody that Chinese people have a lot of food and that they eat cats and dogs for other reasons, can I say:

> The reason why Chinese people eat cats and dogs is not because of **the** lack of food.

Would it be mistaken for "Chinese people don't have food, but they don't eat cats and dogs for not having food but for other reasons." because the "**the** lack of food" over here kind of makes me think like they are having that kind of problem, which is not exactly what I meant.

Or I should say it without a "the"

> The reason why Chinese people eat cats and dogs is not because of lack of food.

If you could, please also explain how the article "the" works in cases like this?

It is just a example sentence. Please forgive me if you get offended. By the way - I am Chinese, so I can't be racist, right? lol

Comment: Do they really eat cats? :'(

Comment: Is there or is there not a lack of food  in China? You mention "*the lack of food over here."*  Your question is not clear.

Comment: They're *per*fectly delicious.

Comment: If you wanted to omit the article, I'd rephrase the sentence: _The reason ... is not because **they** lack food._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider these two versions of the same humourous rhyme:

> It wasn't the cough that [carried him off](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carry%20off), it was the coffin they carried him off in
>
> It wasn't a cough that carried him off, it was the coffin they carried him off in

Setting aside the fact that the second one isn't as funny, note that the use of **the** in the first sentence strongly suggests that he **did** have a cough but dismisses it as the cause of his death. The second sentence dismisses a cough as the cause of his death, but gives no information about whether he had a cough or not.

Using **the** indicates that you are talking about something specific, something that does exist.  "the lack of food" therefore does suggest that there is a food shortage. Your second sentence is nearly OK, but you don't need **why**. Here is the corrected sentence:

> The reason Chinese people eat cats and dogs is not because of lack of food.

A more idiomatic way of expressing what you want is like this sentence, which I found with [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lack) definition of lack:

> If he ​fails it won't be for lack of ​effort.

**For** in this sentence means **because of**, so you don't need to start the sentence with **the reason why**.  Note that I have changed **if** to **when** because we know that Chinese people do eat cats and dogs. Here is a revised sentence:

> When Chinese people eat cats and dogs, it's not for lack of food.